# Ruby: require 'irbtools' raises LoadError

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I installed the [irbtools](https://github.com/janlelis/irbtools) gem, but I can't require it.

```
$ sudo gem1.9.1 install irbtools
Successfully installed irbtools-0.8.7
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for irbtools-0.8.7...
Building YARD (yri) index for irbtools-0.8.7...
Installing RDoc documentation for irbtools-0.8.7...

$ gem1.9.1 which irbtools  # yup, installed OK
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/irbtools-0.8.7/lib/irbtools.rb

$ ls /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/irbtools-0.8.7/lib/
irbtools  irbtools.rb

$ ruby1.9.1 -e 'require "irbtools"'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `require': no such file to load -- irbtools (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `rescue in require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

It doesn't work in irb1.9.1 either.  All other gems in `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gem` seem to be working fine.  Now I'm kinda dumbstruck.

Can anyone please help me track down what's going on?  I'm not necessarily looking for a solution, but just an idea what to do to debug the problem.

I'm on Debian Squeeze with

```
$ ruby1.9.1 --version
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i486-linux]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is quite strange... I haven't got a debian here, but a generic solution would be to [use rvm or build ruby from source](https://rbjl.janlelis.com/19-rubybuntu-1-installing-ruby-and-rails-on-ubuntu).

Hints for debugging the problem:

- Does requiering or loading */var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/irbtools-0.8.7/lib/irbtools.rb* directly work?
- Do your ruby binary and your gem binary really refer to the same installation?
- Can **irbtools** be found with the Gem.source_index method?: Gem.source_index.gems.keys.grep /irbtools/

Comment: Ah, awesome -- thanks for the ideas!  `require '/.../irbtools.rb'` indeed does not work, and trying `less` on the same path yields `Permission denied`.  As it turns out, a few of the files are mode 600 owned by root.  I think this is because your gem distribution tarball has them as mode 600: http://pastie.org/1786887  I'm not sure what the standard way to do permissions in gems is, but how about uploading a new gem version with all files world-readable?  I've never had this problem with any other gem, so I guess everyone else uses 644.

Comment: Done with 0.8.8 ;) [somehow this bug happened to 0.8.7 oO]

Comment: Thanks, permissions are looking fine!  Now I am having the same problem with the Zucker gem -- for example zucker-9/lib/zucker/env.rb is mode 600. ^_^  Sorry for only noticing now!

Comment: zucker-10 released, which fixes it for Zucker.