# Including gems in ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ubuntu-11.04

I've got a problem with running an additional gem under ubuntu 11.04. I installed `spiceweasel` via gem install - which put it in `/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/spiceweasel`. When I try to run it, I get:

```
`require': no such file to load -- spiceweasel/version (LoadError)
```

The file is in `/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/spiceweasel-0.7.1/lib/spiceweasel/version.rb` but cannot be loaded. This happens both with and without `-rubygems`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you install ruby via repos, via rvm or by source? Does `ruby -S gem list` list the gem?

Comment: Ruby is from repos. gem list lists spiceweasel under localgems.

Comment: What happens when you try to load it using the absolute path?

Comment: I'm able to import the library with either the path set explicitly, or by importing from the directory. No permission problems in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the same problem like here: [Ruby: require 'irbtools' raises LoadError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541059/ruby-require-irbtools-raises-loaderror)

The gem author published the gem with wrong permissions. You should contact the gem author.

Comment: As per comment above - checked the permissions, but they're ok.